# Difference between file://android_assets/ and http://someurl.com/?

Tags: android

I have a android app, that loads images from a JSON file on the web. The JSON file has a url in it with the location on the image. Normally, the app reads the JSON file to download the images from a web adres. But now I want to download the files from my assets folder, and read the JSON file in my assets directory (I'm using file://android_assets).

My first problem is, why can't read the json file from my assets folder?

My JSON files, Not really needed to solve my first problem but I just post it:

Old JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Blue Calmness",
    "thumburl": "http://someurl.com/1.jpg",
    "previewurl": "http://someurl.com/1.jpg",
    "url": "http://someurl.com/1.jpg",
    "text": "Give your background a special message! An inspirational image, the texture and its calm blue color are stimulating and representing the silent word of the see. For a positive look at the world."
}
]
```

New JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Blue Calmness",
    "thumburl": "file:///android_assets/1.jpg",
    "previewurl": "file:///android_assets/1.jpg",
    "url": "file:///android_assets/1.jpg",
    "text": "Give your background a special message! An inspirational image, the texture and its calm blue color are stimulating and representing the silent word of the see. For a positive look at the world."
}
]
```

But I get the error message:

```
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.ScroidWallpaperGallery$FillGalleryTask.handleUncaughtException(ScroidWallpaperGallery.java:415)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.util.threading.LongTimeRunningOperation$InnerAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LongTimeRunningOperation.java:87)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access              $600(AsyncTask.java:177)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:626)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.dao.wallpapers.WallpaperDAO.download(WallpaperDAO.java:105)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.dao.wallpapers.WallpaperDAO.getAvailableWallpapers(WallpaperDAO.java:61)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.core.wallpapers.WallpaperManager.loadAvailableWallpapers(WallpaperManager.java:92)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.ScroidWallpaperGallery$FillGalleryTask.onRun(ScroidWallpaperGallery.java:425)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.main.ScroidWallpaperGallery$FillGalleryTask.onRun(ScroidWallpaperGallery.java:1)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.util.threading.LongTimeRunningOperation$InnerAsyncTask.doInBackground(LongTimeRunningOperation.java:73)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at app.wallpaper.util.threading.LongTimeRunningOperation$InnerAsyncTask.doInBackground(LongTimeRunningOperation.java:1)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   04-29 21:52:42.169: E/AndroidRuntime(23408):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My code to download json from server:

```
    @Inject
WallpaperDAO(IWallpaperParser wallpaperParser) {
    super();

    this.wallpaperParser = wallpaperParser;
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see app.wallpaper.main.dao.wallpapers.IWallpaperDAO#getAvailableWallpapers(android.content.Context)
 */
public Wallpaper[] getAvailableWallpapers(Context context) throws WallpaperListReceivingException {     
    try {
        String data = this.download(URI.create(context.getString(R.string.galleryUrl)), 
                                    new TextFileHttpResponseHandler(),
                                    MAX_DOWNLOAD_RETRIES);

        List<Wallpaper> wallpapers = this.wallpaperParser.parse(data);

        return wallpapers.toArray(new Wallpaper[wallpapers.size()]);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        throw new WallpaperListReceivingException(context.getString(R.string.receivingException), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new WallpaperListReceivingException(context.getString(R.string.receivingException), ex);
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {
        throw new WallpaperListReceivingException(context.getString(R.string.parseExceptionText), ex);
    }
}
```

Where galleryUrl is file://android_assets/myfile.json

Now I am wondering, why can't android load my JSON file from my assets folder, while it can from my webserver. And is there a way to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add more details like what the download function does and also please add more logcat data

Comment: Updated :), thank you for trying to help me out!

Comment: Please add the this.download function as well as that will tell what code part of the code generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

*file:///* represents a URI different from an HTTP URI, which points to the data contained within your assets directory. Your download method is clearly designed for HTTP URLs.

In order to load data from your assets directory you can use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) and the [open](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method in particular.

For example:

```
AssetManager assetMgr = this.getAssets()
InputStream is = assetMgr.open("1.jpg");
```